# coldfusion struct in function argument

Tags: facebook, coldfusion, structure

I'm trying to do server side facebook connect, but the sdk ([get it here](https://github.com/affinitiz/facebook-cf-sdk/wiki/Installation)) provided gives the following error:

```
Invalid CFML construct found on line 523 at column 78.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

{
```

And it doesn't explain why it's throwing this error. I'm not good at cfscript, so I don't know whether the sdk uses the correct syntax, but it throws the error on this function, at the braces of the struct in the function arguments:

```
private String function getUrl(String path = "", Struct parameters = {})
{
    var key = "";
    var resultUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/" & arguments.path;
    if (structCount(arguments.parameters)) {
        resultUrl = resultUrl & "?" & serializeQueryString(arguments.parameters);
    }
    return resultUrl;
}
```

I had thought that using an sdk would be a no brainer, but apparently I'm missing something.
What am I doing wrong?

**Part 2:**
The code now comes to a halt at:

```
for (var propertyName in arguments.properties) {
        httpService.addParam(type="formField", name=propertyName, value=arguments.properties[propertyName]);
    }
```

Are you not allowed to use a for loop in cfscript?

Comment: Are you more comfortable with CF tags? I have converted the PHP version from the facebook docs into CFML, if you want me to post that?

Comment: CF does not allow method argument defaults to be set using the literal notation (array or struct). You must use structNew() as duncan has pointed out.

Comment: @Kristian82: If you feel like sharing, please do. It's not because I'm more comfortable with tags that I shouldn't learn to work with script..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try structNew() or "#structNew()#" instead of {}

Comment: structNew() helps me get past the error (I updated my original post), but the code hangs on another line of the sdk now. I'm seriously wondering if this has been tested before being put online.. : \
Could anybody test the sdk as well to make sure I'm not doing something horribly wrong..?

Comment: I'd guess it should be 'for (propertyName in arguments.properties)' NOT 'for (var propertyName in arguments.properties)'

Comment: I think that support for the `var` keyword, eg. `for (var foo in bar)` was added in CF 9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

This should work for connecting to Facebook and getting an access token:

```
<cfset appID = ""/>
<cfset secret_key = ""/>
<cfset app_url = ""/>


<cfparam name="URL.Code" default="0">
<cfparam name="URL.state" default="0">
<cfparam name="SESSION.Redirect" default="0">
<cfset code_ = URL.Code>


<cfif code_ EQ "" OR code_ EQ 0>
<cfset SESSION.State = Hash(CreateUUID(),"MD5")>
<cfset dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" & appID &      "&redirect_uri=" & app_url & "&scope=email,user_photos,publish_stream" & "&state=" &     SESSION.State>
<cflocation url="#dialog_url#" addtoken="no">
</cfif>

<cfif SESSION.State EQ URL.State>
<cfset token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" & appID & "&redirect_uri=" & app_url & "&client_secret=" & secret_key & "&code=" & code_>

<cfhttp url="#token_url#" result="AccessToken" method="GET">

<cfelse>
<p>The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.</p>
</cfif>
```

Comment: excellent, this helped me figure out what was wrong with the files.. ^^